# Remove outer Array and change display array

Tags: php, laravel, multidimensional-array

If you have an array within an array, how can you remove the outer array in this laravel code. Current return array.

```
 return view($this->_viewDefaultFile)
       ->with('id', $this->_formId)
       ->with('class', $this->_formClass)
       ->with('elements', $this->_formElements)
       ->with('ManageJs', $this->_formManageJs);
```

Current Results

```
[
  0 {
    "id": "id",
    "group": 0,
    "type": "hidden",
    "label": "",
    "options": [

    ],
    "value": "1"
  },
  1 {
    "id": "taskstream",
    "group": 0,
    "type": "text",
    "label": "Task Stream",
    "options": {
      "class": "",
      "validation": "required"
    },
    "value": "System down for maintenance"
  }
]
```

But preferred output

```
[
      id {
        "id": "id",
        "group": 0,
        "type": "hidden",
        "label": "",
        "options": [

        ],
        "value": "1"
      },
      taskstream {
        "id": "taskstream",
        "group": 0,
        "type": "text",
        "label": "Task Stream",
        "options": {
          "class": "",
          "validation": "required"
        },
        "value": "System down for maintenance"
      }
    ]
```

So i want to return the Array with (ID) has the key. Any help please.

Comment: Iterate over first array and create a second.

Comment: Can you give an example. got an idea, but struggling to implement it.

Answer (score 0):

Here it is:

```
$array = []; // your array
$new_array = [];
foreach ($array as $item) {
    $new_array[$item->id] = $item;
}
```